# Smarty value in value

Tags: smarty

How to run like this code

```
$smarty->assign('value','foo');
$smarty->assign('value1','some smarty code with {$value}');
```

In the template, if I use `{$value}`, there can't show value.

Comment: Besides Marcins answer you can also do `$smarty->assign('value1',$smarty->fetch('string:some smarty code with {$value}'));`. This might be better if you want assign multiple vars or using modifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as below in PHP:

```
$smarty->assign('value','foo');
$smarty->assign('value1',"some smarty code with {$smarty->getTemplateVars('value')}");
```

Then in Smarty template file:

```
{$value}
{$value1}
```

Both variables are visible and working in Smarty template file.

However I've never used such functionality. I would rather do it this way:

```
$fooVariable = 'foo';
$smarty->assign('value',$fooVariable);
$smarty->assign('value1','some smarty code with {$fooVariable}');
```